# How to solve Hazelcast C++ client compilation failure in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, g++, hazelcast

I'm trying to run a basic Hazelcast C++ client. I get following errors, could someone please help?

Compilation command:

```
g++ FillMap.cpp -w -pthread -Icpp/Linux_64/external/include -Icpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/include -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS /home/myubuntu/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a
```

Error:

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(NearCacheStatsImpl.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol
>   `_ZTVN9hazelcast6client7monitor4impl18NearCacheStatsImplE' can not be
>   used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(LocalMapStatsImpl.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol`
>   _ZTVN9hazelcast6client7monitor4impl17LocalMapStatsImplE' can not be
>   used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(HazelcastClient.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol
>   `_ZTVN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pIN9hazelcast6client4impl27HazelcastClientInstanceImplEEE'
>   can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(KeyStateMarkerImpl.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol`
>   _ZTVN9hazelcast6client8internal9nearcache4impl18KeyStateMarkerImplE'
>   can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(NearCacheDataRecord.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol
>   `_ZTVN9hazelcast6client8internal9nearcache4impl6record23AbstractNearCacheRecordINS0_13serialization5pimpl4DataEEE'
>   can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(ClientInvocationFuture.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol`
>   _ZTVN9hazelcast6client3spi4impl22ClientInvocationFuture35InternalDelegatingExecutionCallbackE'
>   can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(ClientInvocation.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when
>   making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(LifecycleService.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against`.rodata' can not be used when making
>   a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(ClientProxy.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol
>   `_ZTVN9hazelcast6client3spi11ClientProxy21EventHandlerDelegatorE' can
>   not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(ProxyManager.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against`.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when
>   making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/radkathimar/hazelcast-cpp-client/cpp/Linux_64/hazelcast/lib/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.a(ClientContext.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a
>   PIE object; recompile with -fPIC

Comment: Did you try `recompile with -fPIC` ?

Comment: I did try, but same result. I'm assuming it is complaining for the static library asking to recompile the library with -fPIC?

Comment: Yes, you have to recompile .a file with -fPIC

Comment: This .a file came as part of the hazelcast c++ client package. Any idea on how to recompile? Probably I need to get the source code and compile it from the scratch?

Comment: You can do it also the other way, recompiling your client code as non-PIC/PIE (`-no-pie` option for gcc linking is probably enough, as you do both compile+linking in one step (I think there's also `-fno-pic` for compile only, but I'm not sure if I remember it correctly, use gcc manual for precise options) ... this is generally sub-optimal solution, but if you can't recompile the sources of the library, you can use it as work-around. (if you don't have sources of that library and the project is not open source, probably run away from it quickly, unless this is one day experiment + delete after)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @RajaNarayan Here is how you can recompile Hazelcast client: clone from github: `git clone --recursive git@github.com:hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client.git` 
Then build the library as you need, for example 64 bit static release library: 
`scripts/build-linux.sh 64 STATIC Release COMPILE_WITHOUT_SSL`
Please see the release script: `https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/blob/master/releaseLinux.sh`
You also need to add the desired flag for Linux in the CMakeLists.txt file at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L197